# After Internationalization Form Validation Doesnot Work

Tags: php, codeigniter

After implementing this Internationalization config on my CI, My form validation does not work anymore.

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n

How should I make it work so the Validation error in another language show up?

I want the result if it's another language , then it is changed. In my case, I am using Indonesian.

```
Kolom 'Name' harus diisi.
Kolom 'Password' harus diisi.
```

Code in Controller:

```
        $this->load->library("form_validation");
        $this->lang->load('data', "id");

        $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(' ', '<br />');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("name", "lang:name", "required|min_length[3]");
        $this->form_validation->set_rules("password", "lang:password", "required|min_length[6]");

        //using application/language
         $this->form_validation->set_message('required', lang("custom_required"));

        if(!$this->form_validation->run()){ exit(validation_errors()); }
```

Code in Language: indonesian/data_lang.php

```
 $lang['custom_required'] = "Kolom %s harus diisi.";
```

Add a folder in **system/language/indonesian** .

```
form_validation_lang.php

  $lang['required']         = "Kolom %s harus diisi.";
```

Edit the language for Indonesian but it still didnot show up.

If I use data_lang in English folder , it would work.

Comment: Did you try this ?
`$this->load->helper('form')`
`echo show_error('name');`
`echo show_error('password')`

Comment: Hi @Amir where is the condition phrase?

Comment: A silly question, but did you add your indonesian language files? Does still work if you use English?

Comment: @Chococroc Hi. form_validation does not work at all at this point.

Comment: Any error in your logs? in CI logs, in your apache? does the application keeps working, and only the validation_errors is not showing, or you have more problems?

Comment: @Chococroc The application is working as it is supposed to but when the form validation codes are running, there is no error shown . it just keep loading in the form validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Form Validation for Internationalization:

The way I am using is revising the system language file.

1. Create a specific language folder in path **system/language/$language**
   You can copy the English folder in the language folder and rename the folder to your
   language. Later ,you can translate the English statement to your choice of language
2. To be able to switch between language , you need to set the config language in the controller

   $this->config->set_item('language', $language);

   PS. Make sure `$language` name is the same as the folder name in the system folder
3. Just run the form_validation . It works!

The other way is a custom_message. This does not have to interfere with the system folder. You can see the usage above in the question .

1. create a language file in path **application/language/$language**

   eg.
    
   **data_lang.php**
   `$lang['custom_required'] = ' text'`
2. Load the language file before accessing the language content.

   $this->lang->load('data', "id");

   $this->form_validation->set_message('required', lang("custom_required"));